# Magento REST API Updating

Tags: magento, rest, model

I have been trying to update a field on a customer information via the REST API using this link format:

```
http://<magentohost>/api/rest/customers
```

But to I am getting a **customer email already exist**

How can I update information via REST API..

Sample Code:

```
        $productData = json_encode(array(
            'id'        => 1,
            'firstname' => 'Ted',
            'lastname'  => 'Mosbius',
            'website_id'=> 1,
            'group_id'     => 1,
            'email'         => 'ted@mosbis.com'
        ));
        $headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json');
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, $productData, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, $headers);
        // $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl);
        $productsList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());
        print_r($productsList);
```

In this code, email exist, id exist , website_id exist and group_id exist... I just wanted to update the firstName and lastName

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am asking, because unfortunately , I haven't found any docs or guide on doing this...

Answer (score 1):

Just found the problem, I need to use **PUT** instead of **POST** when updating based from this link (http://ajaxpatterns.org/RESTful_Service)...

```
$productData = json_encode(array(
    'id'        => 1,
    'firstname' => 'Ted',
    'lastname'  => 'Mosbius',
));
$headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json');
$oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, $productData, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_PUT, $headers);
$productsList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());
print_r($productsList);
```

Hopefully this will help someone in the future... :)

Comment: After getting $productsList how to get product other details like category, name, manufacture etc.

Answer (score 0):

Errors do come up less the header is formed like this:

```
$headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => '*/*');
```